# concating an array of strings in php to 2 or more strings

Tags: php, string

I have the following code, which takes an array of strings, and splits it to 2 strings:

```
$key2 = $count = count($textArray);
$key = 0;
while ($key2 >= $count/2){
    $this -> text1 = $this-> text1 . $textArray[$key];
    $this -> text2 = $textArray[$key2] . $this-> text2;
    $key++;
    $key2--;
}
```

Right now on a 5 index array I get to split it 3-2, I want to make it 2-3, so on text1, i'll only concate 2 string,

This is prolly quite simple thing to do, but I'm not able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I read your question correctly:

```
$strings = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f');

$new = array_map(function ($arr) {
    return implode('', $arr);
}, array(array_splice($strings, 0, floor(sizeof($strings) / 2)), $strings));

print_r($new);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ab
    [1] => cdf
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<?php
$arr = array("qwe","rty","asd","zxc","fgh","xxx","abvah");

$arrNew = array_chunk($arr,ceil(count($arr)/2.0));
$text1 = "";
$text2 = "";

/*foreach ($arrNew[0] as $arr1){
    $text1 .= $arr1;
}
foreach ($arrNew[1] as $arr2){
    $text2 .= $arr2;
}*/
array_map(function($x) use($text1){$text1 .= $x;},$arrNew[0]);
array_map(function($x) use($text2){$text2 .= $x;},$arrNew[1]);

print "$text1\n$text2\n";
?>
```

Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Don't use `global`. Instead you could write your anonymous function as: `function($x) use($text1) {$text1 .= $x;}`.

Comment: @Yoshi: Thanks! :-).. I really never knew about `use(..)`.